# PHP Выбор из массива по части имени ключа

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив вида

```
$array = [
   'name' => 'Имя',
   'surname' => 'Фамилия',
   'phone1' => '+79091111111',
   'phone2' => '+79092222222'
];
```

Количество элементов с ключами начинающимися на phone неизвестно. Как можно выбрать все такие элементы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Стандартная функция `array_filter` осуществляет фильтрацию массива, используя функцию обратного вызова, которая может принимать либо значения, либо значения и ключи.
Внутри функции вам требуется определить, подходит вам текущий ключ или нет. Способов определить, начинается ли строка с искомой не мало.

```
$result = array_filter($data, function($v, $k){
                  return strpos($k, "phone") === 0;
            }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

Comment: Можно [`ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY`](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cb7d08fcab174956584e83a7d0ec342ba39722eb) использовать только для ключей :)

Comment: @Let'ssayPie да, затупил немного.

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант:

```
$array = [
    'name' => 'Имя',
    'surname' => 'Фамилия',
    'phone1' => '+79091111111',
    'phone2' => '+79092222222'
];

$result = preg_grep('/phone\d+/', array_keys($array));

foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    if (!in_array($key, $result))
        unset($array[$key]);
}

print_r($array);
```

Или же такой вариант:

```
$r = array_intersect_key($array, array_flip(preg_grep('/phone\d+/', array_keys($array))));
print_r($r);
```

Comment: `intersect` удобнее будет, наверное, чем циклы гонять

Comment: @teran, уже добавил, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = [
    'name' => 'Имя',
    'surname' => 'Фамилия',
    'phone1' => '+79091111111',
    'phone2' => '+79092222222'
];
$search = 'phone';
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
  if($search == substr($key,0,strlen($search)))
    $result[] = $value
}
```